# Filter out image/file links for Python mechanize web crawler

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, html-parsing, mechanize

I'm writing a simple Python web crawler using the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library.

Right now, I just want to do the following:

1. Accept a list of startURLs as input
2. For each URL in startURLs, grab all the links on the page
3. Then, do an HTTP request for each of those links, and grab all of the links from them ...
4. Repeat this to the specified depth from the startURL.

So my problem is that when it is in step 3, I want it to skip downloading any links that point to image files (so if there is a URL http://www.example.com/kittens.jpg) then I want it to not add that to the list of URLs to fetch.

Obviously I could do this by just using a regex to match various file extensions in the URL path, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to  determine whether or not a URL points to an image file, rather than an HTML document. Is there some sort of library function (either in mechanize, or some other library) that will let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested approach of using a regex on the url is probably the best way to do this, the only way to see for sure what the url points to would be to make a request to the server and examine the [`Content-Type` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) of the response to see if it starts with '`image/`'.

If you don't mind the overhead of making additional server requests then you should send a [`HEAD` request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) for the resource rather than the usual `GET` request - this will cause the server to return information about the resource (including its content type) without actually returning the file itself, saving you some bandwidth.